# Writing file with multiple Chef cookbooks all targeting the same file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I have a situation where I have three cookbooks, each with a template resource that writes to an /etc/hosts file.

Rather than overwriting, I would like to append:

- The first cookbook creates /etc/hosts file and writes lines 1,2,3.
- The second cookbook appends lines 4,5. etc.

What's the right way to handle this in Chef land?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can change a file with chef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848110/how-i-can-change-a-file-with-chef)

Answer (score 2):

You should better create a cookbook managing the file which generate it from attributes.

CookbookA/attributes/default.rb

```
default['hosts']['lines'] = []
```

CookbookA/recipes/genfile.rb

```
template "/etc/hosts" do
  source "hosts.erb"
end
```

CookbookA/templates/default/hosts.erb

```
#File Generated by Chef
<% node['hosts']['lines'].each do |l| %>
<% l -%>
<% end.unless node['hosts']['lines'].empty? %>
```

And then in your other cookbooks attributes files:

```
default['hosts']['lines'] << ["first line","second line"]
```

And have thoose cookbooks depends on CookbookA and in their recipe call `include_recipe "CookbookA::genfile.rb"`

Using `<<` you append to the attribute instead of overwriting them.