# how to replace specific variables in a file using chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to chef, I am trying to replace a specific variable in a file. While running a container a file is generated, I've to replace a value in this by a value I wanted using chef. Leave the container part aside. Is this possible to replace specific variables.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can change a file with Chef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848110/how-i-can-change-a-file-with-chef)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should not modify a file unless the file has really specific part you can't predict/manage yourself.
If you can enforce/know any variable part you should use a [template](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) and render the whole file.

On last resort, there's the [FileEdit Class](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/util/file_edit.rb) you can use to change lines in a file (again this is with high risks).

More details [here](http://sysadvent.blogspot.fr/2012/12/day-24-twelve-things-you-didnt-know.html#item_2).

On last if you really need to do this there's Sean O'Meara cookbook [line](https://github.com/someara/line-cookbook) which does part of the job, ensuring idempotency of the modifications needed.