# How to change value of variable within a file that is copied using cookbook_file resource?

Tags: chef-infra

I am using a cookbook_file resource to copy a file to the node. The file contains a variable as
`HOST_ADDR='x.x.x.x'`

Now, after copying the file to the node, I want to replace value of `Host_ADDR` from `'x.x.x.x'` to `#{node['ipaddress']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [template](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) resource instead and add a variable to the file as follows:

```
HOST_ADDR='<%= node['ipaddress'] %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Chef allows you to do that with `Chef::Util::FileEdit` see for example
[How can I change a file with Chef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848110/how-i-can-change-a-file-with-chef)