# Using chef how to update a file after reading input from another file?

Tags: linux, bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using linux commands to generate a file "a.txt" . Now I need to read the first word of file "a.txt" and update an existing file called "b.txt". I will search a word called "/fill " in b.txt and replace it with the word read from a.txt  Below is the code

```
bash 'example' do

 code <<-EOH
 cat ex.txt >> a.txt 
  EOH
end

test = /#{'cat /a.txt'}/
file_names = ['/b.txt']

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_contents = text.gsub(/fill, test)
  puts new_contents
  File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
```

1. With the help of linux command "cat ex.txt >> a.txt " I am putting the content of ex.txt to a.txt.
2. After this I want to read the file a.txt with  test = /#{'cat /a.txt'}/. Example a.txt contains "azure" word
3. Now in b.txt I want to search for a word "/fill" and replace with content read in step 2 from b.txt file ie azure
4. The problem is instead of replacing /fill with azure, /fill is getting replaced with cat /a.txt. 
   Hope its clear now

Can you please help here

Comment: No we can't help as it sounds absolutely counter productive, why doesn't a `template` and `file` resource works in your case ? relying to bash code should be the last resort when usual idempotent primitive can't fit. This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), describe what you're really after and we may help with approaches.

Comment: @Tensibai its because ex.txt is generated dynamically and I need to read the contents. The goal is to read the content of dynamically generated file called ex.txt and replace the content of the b.txt file based on certain word search. I hope I made my point

Comment: Not you didn't, you don't say why a template doesn't fit for b.txt, nor why  you have to rely on this ex.txt, nor defined what you're doing as a whole.

Comment: Ok I quit, if you can't describe your overall problem and say why you script can't be maanged by chef, and why the ohai information doesn't fit your need, I can't help.

Comment: You're just repeating what you said above. As said, I quit there, nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to follow, what you actually want to achieve. Your code has a few issues. General advice:

- put your ruby code inside a [`ruby_block`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) resource so that is executed during Chef's convergence phase
- Use `Chef::Util::FileEdit`, if you want to edit files that are not entirely managed by Chef (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848110/how-can-i-change-a-file-with-chef) for more inspiration)).
- In case you really want to write the complete file using Chef, use a [`file`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html) resource and specify the `content` based on what you've read using `File.read`.
- As said, ruby code outside of `ruby_block` is executed in the compile phase ([which precedes the *convergence* phase](https://coderanger.net/two-pass/)). If you this is too early (because the source file isn't there yet, you can use a `lazy` block for lazy evaluation:

  ```rb
  file "b.txt" do
    content lazy { File.read .. }
  end
  ```

Comment: thanks for your response. I have reworded the requirements. please help here

Comment: Very hard. As @Tenisbai said it would make sense to describe what you actually want to do without having a solution in mind which does not feel "chef native" (at least to me).