# How to Replace a path with another path using sed in a chef resource

Tags: sed, resources, chef-infra, execute

I have a file which has below path-

## JVM              == /home/user/tools/jdk/bin/java

I want to replace "/home/user/tools/jdk/bin/java" with "/apps/java/bin"

I use below command in chef resource but it does not work-
 sed -i -e 's//home/user/tools/jdk/bin/java//apps/bin/java/' testfilename

I get below error-
           STDERR: sed: couldn't open file ser/tools/jdk/bin/java//apps/bin/java/: No such file or directory

Comment: You need to escape to forward slashes: `\/`

Comment: Have a look at [Chef::FileEdit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848110/how-can-i-change-a-file-with-chef). Don't call `sed` from Chef. Please post your code in your future questions.

Comment: yes I tried with that too-

sed -i -e 's/\/home\/user\/tools\/jdk\/bin\/java/\/apps\/bin\/java/' testfilename

Comment: If the file contains parameter like "JVM == /home/user/tools/jdk/bin/java" in a single line then you can directly replace the line. If not, can you please put the whole line which needs to be updated.

Comment: Is it `apps/bin/java/` or `apps/java/bin`?

Comment: Hi Mrigesh, how can I replace the whole line with JVM == /apps/java/bin    ?

Comment: Stephen,Below is the code I am using. I also tried using the same code with "execute" resource but same error-

bash 'Changing path in filename.txt' do
  code <<-EOH
  cd #{full_app_path}/Applications/#{app_name}.woa.#{woa_build_version}/Contents/UNIX
 sed -i -e "s/\/home\/user\/tools\/jdk\/bin\/java/\/apps\/bin\/java/" filename.txt
  EOH
end

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `line` cookbook for this kind of operation.